# How to prevent Float contents overlap other contents below

Tags: html, css

I have a div with two floats inside of it. The left one contains an image. the right side floats contains text. I want the text to remain by the side of the image, but this text, when too big, expands over the content below, and I can’t stop it from doing so, instead pushing down the content below.

I’ve been playing with overflow and looking around the stackexchange but I’m just not sure how to get it to push things down. I'm really looking for a simple CSS Fix but I can't seem to find out what/where/how!

This is really problematic when viewed on mobile

[**Jsfidle link with CSS**](http://jsfiddle.net/rxaDD/)

Code

```
<div id="pcontents">
<div class="clearfix">
                    <div id="pthumbdiv" style="float:left;"><div class="pthumb"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?> </div></div>
                        <div id="ptextdiv" style="float:left;">
                        <span class="ptitle"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></span>
                        </div>
                        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                    </div>
<span class="pcontent-text"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></span>
</div>
```

Comment: set width and overflow property

Comment: can you create a fiddle link?

Comment: @Kiran http://jsfiddle.net/rxaDD/1/

Comment: if you want to hide the overflowing content you need to set height for ptitle like this http://jsfiddle.net/rxaDD/3/

Comment: @Kiran Not exactly. I would want the text not to be hidden, but to be fully show. Tho when it is fully show it overlaps the content bellow. I guess the overflow property isnt neccesary the thing needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the **.ptitle** element to be positioned as **relative**, not absolute.

```
.ptitle {
   position: relative;
}
```

At least it worked for me. And for further formatting, use margin and padding the way you want the element to align in the page.

Comment: Having it to absolute allows it to be floating next to the image, which is where I would like it to stay. Simply that the text when its too large doesn't overlap the content bellow it, simply pushes it down.

Comment: @user51030 Well, it can not push down things if it's absolute, maybe you should change the positioning of that image then, mess up with margins and paddings. Otherwise I see no solution to this.

Comment: if you were to do it, how would you get an image on the left, the text on the right of it? I'm using divs and floats because It's the way that I know, and its also how I can get the image to be css responsive and resize. But if you see a better way I would love to hear

Comment: The only issues I have with this solution is that if the text is too long it will go under the image

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you define your css using . eg ( .ptextdiv { ... } ) those rules will only be applied to elements of that CLASS not that ID so in your code the definitions for ptextdiv aren't actually being applied to anything at all right now.

I tested the code and removing the position:absolute; declaration caused the text in the bottom div to be pused down.  Is that what you wanted?

Using absolute positioning for an object removes that object from the document flow entirely so absolute positioned elements will never push anything else down.

Comment: Hi @Adam-hollow! I would want the text to stay on the side of the image, but to not overlap the content bellow it, if it is too large, but move it down. so im not sure how to achieve that

Comment: Yep.  Removing the position:absolute worked just fine for that purpose when I tested it.  Absolute positioning should be used very carefully as removing elements from the document flow can have results like what you were getting when you don't know exactly how big elements are going to be because absolutely positioned elements don't interact with other elements in the document flow.  They just sit there, right where you put them, right on top of things.

Comment: Oh and to make the text  stay to the right of the image you float both of them left and you MUST give them both a defined width.  Without a defined width a div element will default to a width of 100% of its container which will automatically move it below the image.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use position absolute anywhere in this case. Have the image & the text next to it wrapped in a DIV and float the parent and the children DIV. This will allow the text to stay next to the image.

Float the container below also and declare a width for the same. This will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove position:absolute on .ptitle 
Add width:20% to pthumbdiv and width:80% to ptextdiv, add float:left to both.

Answer (score 0):

**Replace your css code with this:**  [Here is fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rxaDD/5/)
you were using . instead of # in id

```
.clearfix:after {
  clear:both;
  content:".";
  display:block;
  height:0;
  line-height:0;
  visibility:hidden;
  margin-bottom:13px;

}

.clearfix {
position:relative;

}
/* Hides from IE-mac \*/
* html .clearfix {height: 1%;}
.clearfix {display: block;}

.pimage {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.pimage-class {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 600px;
}

#ptextdiv {
    width:80%;
    height:auto;
}


.ptitle {
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-top:7px;
    height:inherit;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: normal;  
        overflow: hidden;

}

.ptitle a{
    text-decoration:none;
}

.ptitle a:hover {   
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#FC0;

}

#pthumbdiv {
    width:20%;
    position:relative;

}

.pthumb {
    max-width:48px;
    max-height:48px;
    padding: 0;
    margin-right:15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 55px;
    -moz-border-radius: 55px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 55px;  
    border-radius: 55px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.pcontent {
    width:600px;
}
```